# Is there a way to send with FCM a push notification directly to a specific device?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am doing an application in health in Nativescript and using https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase 
where I need to send a specific user a notification to alert him about something.

I have seen that to send to a specific device, the registration token can be used but is there any other way?

PS : when the user log in, I have an internal id that can be used to identify the user.

Comment: Why not use the registration token? I usually store the registration token in a DB on first use of the app and use it for device specific Push Notifications.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to securely target an individual device.  The registration token is **the** way the FCM identifies the device.

If you would like a non-secure way of delivering the message, you could try to use a uniquely named [topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging), but be aware that any device attached to your project will be able to listen to every topic if they just know the name.